# Knockout: Change css class based on value of observable

Tags: javascript, css, knockout.js

I use foreach on an observable array:

```
<div id="mainRight" data-bind="foreach: notifications">
    <div class="statusRow">
        <div class="leftStatusCell">
            <div class="leftStatusCellColor" data-bind="css: availabilityCssClass($data.availability)"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="topRightStatusCell" data-bind="text: sip"></div>
        <div class="bottomtRightStatusCell ellipsisSingleline" data-bind="text: note"></div>
    </div>
</div> <!== end mainRight ==>
```

As you can see, I pass the current value of availability to the function availabilityCssClass, which compares the value to some predefined strings. Depending on the matching string, it returns a class name.

```
self.availabilityCssClass = ko.computed(function (value) {
    var availability = value;
    if (availability === "Busy" || "DoNotDisturb" || "BeRightBack")
        return "leftStatusCellColorOrange";
    else if (availability === "Away" || "Offline")
        return "leftStatusCellColorRed";
    else
        return "leftStatusCellColorGreen";
});
```

This is my model. The data comes from an external data source.

```
function Notification(root, sip, availability, note) {
    var self = this;

    self.sip = ko.observable(sip);
    self.availability = ko.observable(availability);
    self.note = ko.observable(note);
};

self.notifications = ko.observableArray();
```

However, it doesnt work as is. When the computed function is not commented out, the foreach does not iterate over the data and the div is empty. But I can see that the viewModel is not empty.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle, and describe what doesn't work.

Comment: Which KO version are you using?

Comment: Im using 2.2 so this functionality should be supported, right?

Comment: The class is not applied according to evaluated value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot pass value into computed in such way. It is better to add this computed to `Notification` view model and use `self.availability` property:

```
function Notification(root, sip, availability, note) {
    var self = this;

    self.sip = ko.observable(sip);
    self.availability = ko.observable(availability);
    self.note = ko.observable(note);

    self.availabilityCssClass = ko.computed(function() {
        var availability = self.availability();

        if (["Busy", "DoNotDisturb", "BeRightBack"].indexOf(availability) != -1) return "leftStatusCellColorOrange";
        else if (["Away", "Offline"].indexOf(availability) != -1) return "leftStatusCellColorRed";
        else return "leftStatusCellColorGreen";
    });
};
```

Your `if` statement wasn't correct, so I fixed the logic. Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vyshniakov/Jk7Fd/

Comment: That is awesome, thank you! Why cant I pass the value to the computed function like I did? And what was wrong with the if-statement?

Comment: I don't know why but passing values to computed doesn't work :). In javascript you cannot compare value in such way you did it. In your code first 'if' will always return true when availability is not Busy.

Comment: Just noticed that the note value is overwritten each time the availability changes. How can I avoid this?

Comment: It shouldn't. Maybe there is another code in your project that does it, but didn't post it.

Comment: Yes, I have this:

    //Add or update with empty values supplied
    `self.addNotification = function (sip, availability, note) {
        var existingItem = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.notifications(), function (item) {
            return item.sip().toLowerCase() == sip
        });

        if (existingItem) {
                existingItem.availability(availability);
                existingItem.note(note);
        }
        else {
            self.notifications.push(new Notification(self, sip, availability, note));
        }
        self.notifications.sort();
    };`

Comment: When I change the note, it resets the availability. And when I change the availability, it resets the note. Hmm.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make `availabilityCssClass` a function. As you've written it, it's not a computed observable since it has no observable dependencies.

```
self.availabilityCssClass = function (value) {
    var availability = value;
    if (availability === "Busy" || "DoNotDisturb" || "BeRightBack")
        return "leftStatusCellColorOrange";
    else if (availability === "Away" || "Offline")
        return "leftStatusCellColorRed";
    else
        return "leftStatusCellColorGreen";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS binding wants a object literal with the name of the CSS class as member name and the value true or false depeding on you want to remove or add the class

```
data-bind="css: { 'css-class-name': true }"
```

edit: Hmm, they have changed the css binding in 2.2 ;)