# Knockout: Change CSS visibility based on observable value

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I'm trying to set CSS class with `display: none` attribute for Knockout observable which has no value assigned.

HTML code:

```
    <div class="userParent actionHandle dragHandle">
        <span class="userName" data-bind="text: userName"></span><span class="userDOB" data-bind="text: userDOB"></span><span class="userGender" data-bind="text: userGender"></span>
    </div>
```

and Knockout constructor:

```
    this.userName = ko.observable('');
    this.userDOB = ko.observable('');
    this.userGender = ko.observable('');
```

then I clear values

```
    this.userName('');
    this.userDOB('');
    this.userGender('');
```

at that point I want to append CSS which will set/add `display: none` to all `user*` classes.

I have followed solutions from those two questions

- [knockout set css conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28806357/knockout-set-css-conditionally)
- [Knockout: Change css class based on value of observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13453413/knockout-change-css-class-based-on-value-of-observable)

but without luck.

My code for CSS changes looks like

```
self.CssBind = function (k) {

var CssBind = '';

if (self.userName() === '') {
     CssBind = 'none';
}
if (self.userDOB() === '') {
     CssBind = 'none';
}
if (self.userGender() === '') {
     CssBind = 'none';}

 return CssBind;
});
```

and changed HTML

```
 <div class="userParent actionHandle dragHandle">
        <span class="userName" data-bind="text: userName, style: {display $root.CssBind}"></span><span class="userDOB" data-bind="text: userDOB, style: {display $root.CssBind}"></span><span class="userGender" data-bind="text: userGender, style: {display $root.CssBind}"></span>
    </div>
```

I think there must be something easy what I have missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [computed](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) property instead of a function (also use more a relatable property name – "CssBind" means absolutely nothing)

```
self.everythingIsFilledIn = ko.pureComputed(function () {
    return self.userName() > '' && self.userDOB() > '' && self.userGender() > '';

    // or, for short
    // return self.userName() && self.userDOB() && self.userGender();
});
```

and in the view:

```
<div class="userParent actionHandle dragHandle" data-bind="visible: everythingIsFilledIn">
    <span class="userName" data-bind="text: userName"></span>
    <span class="userDOB" data-bind="text: userDOB"></span>
    <span class="userGender" data-bind="text: userGender"></span>
</div>
```

Use the `visible` binding if you want to show or hide elements based on some truth value. There is no need to fiddle with the CSS binding for such a simple task.

Comment: I have expected that can be handled in a simpler way. Thank you sir.